# Could not fetch "chain" ID for Custom TESTNET at MetaMask

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, prysm, chainid

I am currently trying to create a custom public PoS testnet using the example found in the link: https://docs.prylabs.network/docs/advanced/proof-of-stake-devnet

My node (PC) is connected to a router, receiving a private IP address, and I have completed the port forwarding process to allow external connections.

[image: port forwarding]

However, MetaMask(which is executed from laptop's chrome browser. not connected with same router) still seems unable to find my RPC and does not recognize the chainID of my testnet.(Only 1 picture here but I tried all of the port 5222~5555) Could you let me know if there is a problem with my command syntax or configuration file?

1. Is it impossible because my network is from private ip which is port forwarded?
2. Did I miss something to connect with MetaMask?

**genesis.config (except alloc because it's too long)**

```
{
"config": {
    "chainId": 142536,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "daoForkSupport": true,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "istanbulBlock": 0,
    "muirGlacierBlock": 0,
    "berlinBlock": 0,
    "londonBlock": 0,
    "arrowGlacierBlock": 0,
    "grayGlacierBlock": 0,
    "shanghaiTime": 1705910791,
    "terminalTotalDifficulty": 0,
    "terminalTotalDifficultyPassed": true
},
"nonce": "0x0",
"timestamp": "0x65ae2207",
"extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000123463a4b065722e99115d6c222f267d9cabb5240000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"gasLimit": "0x1c9c380",
"difficulty": "0x1",
"mixHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"alloc": {},
"number": "0x0",
"gasUsed": "0x0",
"parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"baseFeePerGas": null,
"excessBlobGas": null,
"blobGasUsed": null 
}
```

**geth command**

```
./geth --networkid 142536 --http --http.api eth,net,web3 --http.addr "0.0.0.0" --http.corsdomain "192.168.0.8:8000" --http.vhosts "192.168.0.8:8001" --ws --ws.api eth,net,web3 --ws.addr "0.0.0.0" --authrpc.jwtsecret jwt.hex --datadir gethdata --nodiscover --syncmode full --allow-insecure-unlock --unlock 0x123463a4b065722e99115d6c222f267d9cabb524
```

**beacon-chain command**

```
./beacon-chain --datadir beacondata --min-sync-peers 0 --genesis-state genesis.ssz --bootstrap-node= --interop-eth1data-votes --chain-config-file config.yml --contract-deployment-block 0 --chain-id 142536 --accept-terms-of-use --jwt-secret jwt.hex --suggested-fee-recipient 0x123463a4B065722E99115D6c222f267d9cABb524 --minimum-peers-per-subnet 0 --enable-debug-rpc-endpoints --execution-endpoint gethdata/geth.ipc
```

**validator command**

```
./validator --datadir validatordata --accept-terms-of-use --interop-num-validators 64 --chain-config-file config.yml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem it's because I use wrong geth command!!!

```
--http.corsdomain "192.168.0.8:8000" --http.vhosts "192.168.0.8:8001"
```

I totally misunderstood this options, I need to set these like this!

```
--http.corsdomain "*" --http.vhosts "*"
```

Now I can connect to my network with MetaMask!

Comment: I will accept my answer soon.... sorry for that. I need to wait for 2 days to accept...